# Definition of mapping telescope

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, quotient-spaces, cw-complexes

In Kochman's stable homotopy theory, pg 121 prop 4.24

> We let $X$ be a based CW complex. Let $X^n$ be an increasing sequence of subcomplex whose union equals $X$. We define 
>   $$TX = \bigcup_{n \ge -1} [n-1,n]\ltimes X^n \subseteq [-2,\infty) \ltimes X$$
>   where we let $X^{-1}=*$.

My confusion. Today I have learnt that $\ltimes$ denotes the half smash product: 
$$(X,x) \ltimes Y := X \wedge Y_+ \cong X \times Y/\{ x\} \times Y$$

> **Now how does $[n-1,n] \ltimes X^n$ live in $[-2,\infty) \ltimes X$?**

Comment: Here you should have $[n,n+1]\ltimes X =[n,n+1]_+\wedge X=[n,n+1]\times X/[n,n+1]\times\ast$. Unfortunately different authors have different conventions as to when $\ltimes$ and write $\rtimes$. To avoid confusion it may be a good idea just to write $X_+\wedge Y$ explicitly. Obviously if one of $X$ or $Y$ is an unbased space then there is only one possibility for what is meant by $X\ltimes Y$.