# Problem with the notation in the mapping telescope

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I am studying the proof of proposition 4.2.2 of [this book](https://bookstore.ams.org/fim-7) and the author uses the mapping telescope of a CW-complex $X$ using the following notation

$T(X)=\cup_{n\geq -1}[n-1,n]\ltimes X^{n}$

Could someone explain to me what $\ltimes$ stand for? I have seen it multiple times but I do not know the definition of it.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3193828.